# Weed out variables with less than two factors

Tags: r, apply, sapply

My variables in my dataframe have character observations (not sure if this is the correct way to phrase this, essentially the data is listed as "chr" when I pull up the structure).

I want to first convert everything to factors then check the number of factor levels. Once they are factors, I only want to continue using the variables in the dataframe that have two or more levels.

This is my idea so far. I know `for` loops are kind of taboo in R but I'm pretty new and it makes sense to me to use it.

```
x = as.character(c("Not Sampled", "Not Sampled", "Y", "N"))
y = as.character(c("Not Sampled", "Not Sampled", "Not Sampled", "Not Sampled"))
z = as.character(c("Y", "N", "Not Sampled", "Y"))
df = data.frame(x, y, z)

for i in df:
  df$Response = as.factor(df[,i]) #create new variable in dataframe
  df$Response = df@data[sapply ....  #where I think I can separate out the variables I want and the variables I don't want

  m1 = lm(response ~ 1) #next part where I want only the selected variables
```

I know the solution is probably much more complicated but this is my fledgling attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% lapply(factor) %>% data.frame()
df[ , sapply(df, n_distinct) >= 2]
```

Comment: You don't need dplyr for this lapply approach. (you could use `mutate_each` if you wanted to use dplyr)

Answer (score 4):

the default data.frame method converts strings to factors, so the extra conversion is not necessary in this case.  `lapply` is better for the levels comparison, since `sapply` will try to simplify the return value to a matrix if the lengths are the same.

```
df = data.frame(x, y, z)

## Already factors,  use sapply(df, typeof) to see underlying representation
sapply(df, class)  
#        x        y        z 
# "factor" "factor" "factor" 

## These are the indicies with > 2 levels
lengths(lapply(df, levels)) > 2
#    x     y     z 
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE 

## Extract only those columns
df[lengths(lapply(df, levels)) > 2]
```

Comment: This seems like it will help me. I tried to copy and paste it to test it out, but I'm not sure if "lengths" is a different function or if it is a typo of the base function "length." I'm 99% sure it's the latter, but just for posterity's sake I wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 3):

```
df[, sapply(df, function(x) length(levels(x)) >= 2)]
```